# Failed to create the JVM

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Failed to Create the Java Virtual Machine

i found lots of issues like the one i postedd but i didn't get it well , so im here posting this and hoped someone care >.<

here's my eclipse.ini

-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar

--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120913-144807

-product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.adtproduct

-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform

--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m

--launcher.defaultAction
openFile

-vmargs

-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6

-XX:MaxPermSize=256m

-Xms512m

-Xmx1024m

----------- help me please ................

Answer (score 0):

I guess you got this error when starting eclipse. 
First at least you need jre 1.6.
Second define the jdk to system path variable.
/java directory/bin 
I guess these two can solve your problem

Comment: oh no Thank You .... :)
 i think im too stupid , I've already downloaded the jre but still i forgot to install it

Answer (score 0):

You should download JRE 1.7 if you can, but you need at least 1.6. After that go [HERE](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml), and (based on your OS) set the PATH variable. After that, you should make/edit a/the (This depends on if you have one or not) CLASSPATH variable so you can import Java packages/classes. On my personal computer, I specifically set another path within CLASSPATH to my personal classes, although I'm not sure if that's required or not.